# Design Patterns - what to use when the return type is different

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, architecture

How would you architect this solution where you have different type of search, like web, image  etc.
So in effect the input is same but the result are different according to search type selected

I can think of Strategy n Factory to handle input and select different search algorithm but how to handle return type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the details but yeah an Abstract Factory OR Strategy pattern would fit. About the return type it depends on many things. Starting by simply using object to use generic classes. E.g. you could use the return type, even the object, as a Factory parameter to return a your specfic object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have a `BaseSearchResult` kind of class or have the result `interfaced`, so that different types of search classes can return same type of result.

Edit: you can also go with generics, something like this:

```
class SearchByType1<T>
{
   public T ExecuteSearch()
   {
   }
}
```

By base class I mean if you could have some common and essential properties of all kinds of search result you can create a baseclass and return that by executing searches, similar idea with interfaces.

Comment: Thanks I have been trying this out and generics work for me better.

Answer (score 0):

the search result could return 2 properties:

- type of search result
- the payload (the search result itself)

Example:

```
using System;

public enum SearchResultType
{
    WebPage = 1,
    Image = 2,
    Video = 3,
    Tweet = 4
}

public class SearchResult
{
    public SearchResultType SearchResultType { get; set; }
    public Object Payload { get; set; }

    public SearchResult()
    {
    }
}
```

the payload type can be either an Object, or a BaseSearchResultPayload abstract class from which WebPageSearchResultPayload and ImageSearchResultPayload would inherit. you could also use generics or dynamic if that suits your needs, that depends on the details and context of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, since @AD.Net replied before you and i ended up using generic i have accepted that as answer.